# Displaying JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am still stuck on what should seem to be a simple concept. I have a very very simple javascript that just does some addition and I want to display the result on a web page. I have tried using a  tag but that did not seem to do anything, an now I am trying to use the  from the html but that is not working either. This seems like it should be such a simple thing to do but I am obviously missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have attached the html code, the script, and the css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>The Lighthouse</title>
    <link href="lhouse.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="title">
        <p><img src="logo.jpg" alt="The Lighthouse" />
        </p>
        <p>The Lighthouse<br />
        543 Oak Street<br />
        Owensboro, KY &nbsp;&nbsp;42302<br/>
        (270) 555-7511
        </p>
</div>

    <div id="data_list">
        <table rules="rows" cellspacing='0'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>2011-09-18</td>
                    <td id="amount1">125</td>
                    <td>Nina</td>
                    <td>Largent</td>
                    <td>88 Regal Lane<br />Willaimsburg, KY 40789</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="yellowrow">
                    <td>2011-09-18</td>
                    <td id="amount2">75</td>
                    <td>Mike</td>
                    <td>Hunt</td>
                    <td>404 Barrow Street<br />London, KY 40742</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2011-09-16</td>
                    <td id="amount3">50</td>
                    <td>Monica</td>
                    <td>Lang</td>
                    <td>743 Stawlings Drive<br />Danville, KY 40423</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="yellowrow">
                    <td>2011-09-15</td>
                    <td id="amount4">150</td>
                    <td>William</td>
                    <td>McKnight</td>
                    <td>404 Barrow Street<br />Danville, KY 40423</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2011-09-14</td>
                    <td id="amount5">250</td>
                    <td>Latrina</td>
                    <td>Hults</td>
                    <td>750 Whitehall Road<br />London, KY 40742</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="yellowrow">
                    <td>2011-09-13</td>
                    <td id="amount6">50</td>
                    <td>Danny</td>
                    <td>Shamblin</td>
                    <td>123 Smith Street<br />Owensboro, KY 42303</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="totals">
        <table rules="groups" cellspacing="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="sumTitle" colspan="2">Summary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Contributors</th>
                    <td id="contributions"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <td id="amount"> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

__

```
// JavaScript Document
window.onload = function ()
{
//find the div tags called amount1, amount2, ...amount6
var amount1 = 125;
var amount2 = 75;
var amount3 = 50;
var amount4 = 150;
var amount5 = 250;
var amount6 = 50;
var totalAmount = amount1 + amount2 + amount3 + amount4 + amount5 + amount6;
var totalContributors = 6;

$("contributions").value = totalAmount.toFixed(2);

}
```

__

```
#title {
    width: 600px;
    text-align:right;
    color: rgb(192,142,90);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(232,182,130);
    margin-bottom:9px;
    font-size:10pt;
    height: 100px;
}

#title img {
    float: left;
}

#data_list {
    float: left;
}

table {
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid brown;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.yellowrow {
    background-color: yellow;
}

th {
    color: white;
    background-color: brown;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}

td {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}

.amt {
    text-align: right;
}

#totals table  {
    font-size: 12pt;
    border: solid black 1px;
}

#totals table th {
    text-align: left;
}

#totals table td {
    text-align: right;
    width: 75px;
}

#totals table #sumTitle {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: `$("contributions")` is looking for a `<contributions>..</contributions>` element on the page.

Comment: Also, please only include the least amount of code that illustrates your problem. Do we really need to see *all* of that HTML?

Comment: Also, if you're using jQuery, you should consider using some of the functionality provided; i.e. `$('#selector').html(totalAmount.toFixed(2));`

Comment: You don't include the jquery library and  if you want to write the result inside the td with id `contributions` you have to write something like: $("#contribtuions").html( totalAmount.toFixed(2) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below line:

```
$("contributions").value = totalAmount.toFixed(2);
```

You have forgot # as contributions is id of td so use this:

```
$("#contributions").html(totalAmount.toFixed(2));
```

And `.value` is the javascript and you are using jQuery so use `.html` function instead of `.value` .

And you have not added jquery library in your HTML page, add jquery library also.
And If your JS is in different file then add the file also in the code.

Use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="your/file/path/*.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for presenting everything so clearly. I still have a way to go to fully understand all the ins and outs, but your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("contributions").value = totalAmount.toFixed(2);
```

this should probably be:

```
$("#contributions").html(totalAmount.toFixed(2));
```

So instead it does target the contributions td (based on id because of # just like in css).
And the html sets the innerHTML, you could just use text() instead if it's just plaintext.

Answer (score 1):

2 issues I see:

1) you should be looking for `$("#contributions")` since you are querying by id.

2) since `contributions` is a `td` you should use its innerHTML property to set content, rather than `value`.